# Any alternatives of deprecated property "googlePlusUserId"?

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api

As you can see in Youtube API revision history:

> The channel resource's contentDetails.googlePlusUserId property has been deprecated. Previously, the property was only present if the channel was associated with a Google+ profile. Following the deprecation, the property will no longer be included in any channel resources.

So, how can I understand wich Google account relates to a Youtube Channel?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/38074824/1841839

Comment: I see, but I'm waiting an answer.

Comment: I doubt you will get one.   I don't think there is any real answer.    Google has removed the link between YouTube and Google+ there is no way to get that back.   Except maybe to authenticate the user with both YouTube and Google plus and figure out who they are that way.

Comment: The solution was to call "people/me" Google+ API endpoint and get "id" of currently logged user, as you said.

Answer (score 0):

The only option that I can think of would be to call 
[People: get](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get) using me as the userid.  This will give you the id of the current user.

People: get

Get a person's profile. If your app uses scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login, this method is guaranteed to return ageRange and language. Try it now or see an example.

If using the userId value "me", this method requires authentication using a token that has been granted the OAuth scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login or https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me. Read more about OAuth.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
```

This will require an additional authentication scope.

> If using the userId value "me", this method requires authentication
>   using a token that has been granted the OAuth scope
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login or
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me